# Spring boot doesn't call DisposableBean.destroy() method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean

I kinda shocked today. It is I realized spring-boot doesn't calling `DisposableBean.destroy()`.

For confirmation purposes. I created a very simple empty spring-boot project from `start.spring.io` and I created this bean class. I'm seeing the `afterPropertiesSet` log message but not a `destroy`. What is it? Did I miss something?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SampleBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        log.error("afterPropertiesSet");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        log.error("destroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: What method did you use to trigger the destruction?

Comment: @Jeppz Empty spring boot project stopped itself after a successful start. 
I also tried with Webflux and Rabbitmq starters. It is still the same. In this case, I used `Ctrl+C` to stop application.